# jquery - find element that only has text and not any other html tag

Tags: jquery, html, tags, contains, children

I need to check with jquery that a anchor element only has text in it and not any other tag (img, b) or any thing else.

```
<a href="">TV</a>
```

Should be found, but :

```
<a href=""><img /></a>
```

or:

```
<a href=""><span>TV</span></a>
```

or any other HTML tag, shouldn't be found.

How do i do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can use the [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) function to remove elements which have children (checked using the [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children) method).

```
var emptyAs = $('a').filter(function () {
    return $(this).children().length == 0;
});
```

You could also use the [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) combined with the [`:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/);

```
var moreEmptyAs = $('a:not(:has(*))');
```

You can see both of these working in the following JSFiddle; http://jsfiddle.net/JD67U/

Answer (score -2):

You can try `.text()` this escapes only the text and eliminates every HTML Code.

```
var pureText=$('a').text();
```

Comment: The asker doesn't want to filter; he wants to check.